# I have written a code for the spoj problem "The Next Palindrome" and get wrong answer message on my submissions

Tags: c

I always get wrong answer message on every submission. Please help me out with the code.

The message on every submission is only `wrong answer`

I have tried with all the corner cases and exceptional inputs and the code seem to work properly but the submission is not accepted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int getLength(long long x) {
    int length = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        x = x / 10;
        length++; 
    }
    return length;
}

bool even(long long x) {
    int checkv = 0;
    int pal = x;
    int con = 0;
    int length = getLength(pal);
    length = length / 2;
    while (length--) {
        con = pal % 10;
        checkv = checkv * 10 + con;
        pal = pal / 10;
    }
    if (pal == checkv)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool odd(long long  x) {
    int checkv = 0;
    int pal = x;
    int con = 0;
    int length = getLength(pal);
    length = length / 2;
    while (length--) {
        con = pal % 10;
        checkv = checkv * 10 + con;
        pal = pal / 10;
    }
    pal = pal / 10;
    if (pal == checkv)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

bool checkPal(long long x) {
    int length = getLength(x);
    if (length % 2 == 0)
        return even(x);
    else
        return odd(x);
}

void getPal(long long x) {
    long long pal = x + 1;
    bool again = true;
    while (again) {
        if (checkPal(pal))
            again = false;
        else
            pal++;
    }
    printf("%lli\n", pal);  
}

void main() {
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);
    long long a[n];
    int i = 0;
    while (n--) {
        scanf("%lli", &a[i]);
        getPal(a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I think that the problem lies in the input, i.e, I read the input as `long long` but the actual input may have exceeded the limit of this.

Comment: Use long long instead of int

Comment: Regarding: _...i read the input as long long but the actual input may have exceeded the limit..._, Please provide an example of the _input_ you believe may be causing the problem.  (Edit your post with this information.)

Comment: `void main()` -> `int main()`

Answer (score 1):

Take notice of your compiler warnings.

```
bool even(long long x){
    int checkv = 0;
    int pal = x;            // compiler warning here
    int con = 0;            // used to take value from pal
```

You are immediately losing the significance in the `long long x` by assigning it to `int pal`. The same mistake is in another function too:

```
bool odd(long long  x){
    int checkv = 0;
    int pal = x;            // compiler warning here
    int con = 0;            // used to take value from pal
```

Comment: Your comment for the other answer (now deleted) is correct. Thanks for pointing it out. I think your answer is of more value.  (+1)

Comment: @ryyker I commented before posting an answer, sorry, I usually try not to do that.

Comment: No problem.  I would rather have a mistake pointed out so I can edit or remove it rather than leave it and mislead people.  In this case, your answer addresses the real issue.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your method is a bit slow, it may take too long for very large numbers, upto 4 billion iterations... You should split the number in half, mirror the number's higher digits into the lower digits. If the resulting number is larger, you found the next palindrome, if not, increase the left part and mirror again. That's it. Very quick!